# Set Class Member to Function

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a class that interacts with another class solely through reflection. This class that I am interacting with has some delegates and I am trying to set them. Heres what they look like:

```
public class ClassThatIAmReflecting {
    public delegate void OnSuccessDelegate(bool value);

    public static OnSuccessDelegate OnSuccess;

    public void OnClassThatIAmReflectingSuccess(bool arg) {
        if(OnSuccess != null)
            OnSuccess(arg);
    }
}
```

And here is what I am trying:

```
public class MyClass {

    void Init() {
        Type type = Type.GetType("ClassThatIAmReflecting");

        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("OnSuccess", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(null, HandleOnSuccess);
    }

    void HandleOnSuccess(bool value) {
        // do stuff ...
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is that it cannot convert the action to a object. Any help on how I can do this?

Comment: What is OnSuccess? please show the code of the other class

Comment: OnSuccess is being called via a function that is being called from a C++ dll. The class ClassThatIAmReflecting is a bridge that sits between my C# class and the C++ dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should be:

```
public class MyClass
{

    public void Init()
    {
        Type type = typeof(ClassThatIAmReflecting);
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("OnSuccess", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;

        var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("HandleOnSuccess", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(fieldType, this, methodInfo);

        fieldInfo.SetValue(null, del);

        //test
        ClassThatIAmReflecting.OnSuccess(true);
    }

    private void HandleOnSuccess(bool value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Roma, thanks for your help! This didnt seem to work but I was able to get it running. There was a issue with CreateDelegate and to fix it I pass in `this` instead of `null`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Steph, You are welcome, but it works for me when I pass `null`. Also, it works when I pass `this`.